# Navbar disappears after resizing screen [Bootstrap]

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am simply trying to get the nav bar to toggle when I resize the screen. Right now it simply disapears. I am using bootstrap 3.3.1 and have maxcdn links from the documentation for both the javascript and css in my code. I've been over the documentation but I must be missing something. Below is my exact code. I have changed very little from the example given on the bootstrap website.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse top">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ><a class="top-nav" href="./">About</a></li>
                <li ><a class="top-nav" href="../navbar-static-top/">FAQ</a></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="navbar-form">
                        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-join-waitlist" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signinModal">
                            Get Early Access
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navbar is there but all white so you can't see it.

Add the navbar-default class to the nav element in order to get bootstraps default style / theme:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static" role="navigation">
```